# Show half a widget (an icon)

Tags: flutter

I would like to achive an effect similar to the next one:

[image]

The idea is to have a fully displayed Icon in grey, and then in top of it the same Icon but in another color and only showing on the screen a percentage of the widget on top. I've tried to do it with `Stack` and `Align` (`heightFactor`) but nothing worked well.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Here it's the code I tried:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  GlobalKey aKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Align(
          alignment: const Alignment(-0.85, -0.85),
          child: Wrap(children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Icon(
                        key: aKey,
                        Symbols.thunderstorm,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        size: 100)),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, _) {
                      RenderBox renderbox =
                          aKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

                      return SizedBox(height: renderbox.size.height * 0.25);
                    }),
                    const ClipRect(
                        child: Align(
                      heightFactor:
                          0.5, // Set this to 0.8 to see the displaced, unmatching image.
                      child: Icon(Symbols.thunderstorm,
                          color: Colors.red, size: 100),
                    ))
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

These are the outputs for 0.5 and 0.8 `heightFactor`, respectively:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you include what you've tried and what went wrong?

Comment: try `Stack` with two icons, one of them wrapped with `ClipRect` using a custom `clipper: ...`

Comment: I added the code I tried and the corresponding output @doneforaiur

Comment: @pskink do you have any documentation or tutorial link or can you provide a working example of your solution? I will set it as the answer. And I cannot see exactly how to implement what you recommend without the displacement issue.

Comment: `Stack(children: [blueIcon, ClipRect(clipper: ...., child: redIcon)])`

Comment: I know that part. But don't know what to put in `clipper: ...`,

Comment: I think this might give you an idea; [How to create Wave Curves animation using Clipper Path in Flutter App](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/47/how-to-create-wave-curves-animation-using-clipper-path-in-flutter-app/). I'm not super confident about this but I'm curious about the solution. :^)

Comment: I found a solution that just works well. It automatically solves if you align the coloured widget to the top, so the `heightFactor` cuts from there.

Comment: you need to pass a class extending `CustomClipper<Rect>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ShaderMask` widget to mask the icon with a `gradient` color, and use the `stop` property for the sudden color change.

I created [this demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f3ecf19049191a6535426370ca465eb7) so you can see an example. Run it and click on the icon to see the changes.

```
ShaderMask(
  blendMode: BlendMode.srcIn,
  shaderCallback: (Rect bounds) => RadialGradient(
    center: Alignment.topCenter,
    stops: const [1, 0.5],
    colors: [
      highlightIcon ? Colors.yellow : Colors.grey,
      Colors.grey,
    ],).createShader(bounds),
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.flash_on,
            size: 133,),),
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @pskink's answer, I came up with this working example:

```
class TestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestWidget> createState() => _TestWidgetState();
}

class _TestWidgetState extends State<TestWidget> {
  GlobalKey aKey = GlobalKey();

  double percent = 0.3;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        child: Align(
          alignment: const Alignment(-0.85, -0.85),
          child: Wrap(children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                    child: Icon(
                        key: aKey,
                        Symbols.thunderstorm,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        size: 100)),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, _) {
                      RenderBox renderbox =
                          aKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

                      return SizedBox(
                          height: renderbox.size.height * (1 - percent));
                    }),
                    ClipRect(
                      child: Align(
                          heightFactor: percent,
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: const Icon(Symbols.thunderstorm,
                              color: Colors.red, size: 100)),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Which works as desired. The reason for it is because if you align the coloured widget to the top, the `heightFactor` cuts starting from there. You only need to insert the new cut widget in a Column with a SizedBox with the height you loose from the coloured one.

I couldn't figure out how to configure the `Rect` object @pskink suggested, and it would be appreciated if he could give a detailed code with his full solution to complement this one.

Comment: please don't use such workarounds, what you need is a valid `clipper: ...`, see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cliprect-widget-in-flutter/

Comment: and here's the clipper: `class FooClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
FooClipper(this.heightFactor) : assert(0 <= heightFactor && heightFactor <= 1);

final double heightFactor;

@override
Rect getClip(Size size) => Offset.zero & Size(size.width, size.height * heightFactor);

@override
bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) => false;
}`

Comment: and if you need any vertical alignment use this:  `class FooClipper extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
FooClipper(this.heightFactor, this.alignment) : assert(0 <= heightFactor && heightFactor <= 1);

final double heightFactor;
final Alignment alignment;

@override
Rect getClip(Size size) {
final clipSize = Size(size.width, size.height * heightFactor);
return alignment.inscribe(clipSize, Offset.zero & size);
}

@override
bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) => false;
}`

Comment: can you check my code from my post? could be a simpler solution

Comment: Yours is good, but it displays a sort of radial progress instead of a rect one. Yet, as otherwise I should mark myself as the answer I'll checking yours.

Answer (score -1):

One way to achieve that is using an Stack and two icons, placing one icon above another, and using a ClipRect to cut superior's icons in half, showing the bottom half of the icon behind. Here's an example:

```
Container(
    width: 100,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.bolt,
          size: 100,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        ClipRect(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            heightFactor: 0.5,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.bolt,
              size: 100,
              color: Colors.yellow,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ))
```